# Looking for Debugger for Railo 3.2

Tags: apache, tomcat6, railo

I am looking for a debugger to debug my Railo 3.2 application. The apache web server forwards all requests to Railo 3.2 which running on top of tomcat via jk module library.

I wonder if I can setup breakpoints and debug the code.

I had a look at Fusion Debug but that does not suite Railo 3.2.x.

Thanks for advice in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fusion Debug is the only debugger that I know. What do you mean it doesn't "suite" Railo 3.2? I am pretty sure it works with 3.1.x and above.

Comment: Sorry, suite -> suit (spell mistake )

Comment: Fusion Debug is suitable for 3.1.x but not above, as I understand. Please correct me if I have misunderstood

Comment: Where did you get that from? _Have you actually tried it?_ The [requirements page](http://www.fusion-debug.com/fd/requirements.cfm) specifically mentions Railo 3.2, and I suspect the only reason it doesn't also list 3.3 and 4.0 and 4.1 is because they haven't updated that page.